# How do I declare and use dynamic variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I need to declare a JavaScript variable based on a counter, how do I do so?

```
var pageNumber = 1;
var "text"+pageNumber;
```

The above code does not work.

Answer (score 74):

In JavaScript (as i know) there are 2 ways by which you can create dynamic variables:

1. eval Function
2. window object

eval:

```
var pageNumber = 1;
eval("var text" + pageNumber + "=123;");
alert(text1);
```

window object:

```
var pageNumber = 1;
window["text" + pageNumber] = 123;
alert(window["text" + pageNumber]);
```

Comment: For example, Ihave array in dynamic var `window["text" + pageNumber]` - how to get length of array?

Comment: window["text" + pageNumber].length

Comment: You may probably use any object, not just the `window` one: see Mark Kahn answer.

Answer (score 8):

How would you then access said variable since you don't know its name?  :)  You're probably better off setting a parameter on an object, e.g.:

```
var obj = {};
obj['text' + pageNumber] = 1;
```

if you -really- want to do this:

```
eval('var text' + pageNumber + '=1');
```

Comment: There are lots of ways you might access said vars: looping through a number set where vars are named var1, var2, var3. Or retrieving a unknown set vars and loading them dynamically by looping through a json object and updating global vars, im sure there are lots more scenarios

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do it sing JavaScript.I think you can use an array instead of this,

```
 var textArray=new Array();
    textArray[pageNumber]="something";
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the variable is in the global scope, you could do something like this:

```
var x = 1;
var x1 = "test"
console.log(window["x" + x]); //prints "test"
```

However, a better question might be why you want such behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You could also wrap your counter in an object:

```
var PageNumber = (function() {
  var value = 0;
  return {
   getVal: function(){return value;},
   incr: function(val){
            value += val || 1;
            this['text'+value]=true /*or some value*/;
            return this;
         }
   };
})();

alert(PageNumber.incr().incr().text2); //=>true
alert(PageNumber['text'+PageNumber.getVal()]) /==> true
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `this` keyword in JS:

Eg:

```
var a = [1,2,3];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  this["var" + i] = i + 1;
}
```

then when you print:

```
var0 // 1
var1 // 2
var2 // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed something like this.

I have a list of variables like this:

```
var a = $('<div class="someHtml"></div>'),b = $('<div class="someHtml"></div>'),c = $('<div class="someHtml"></div>');
```

I needed to call them using another variable that held a string with the name of one of these variables like this:

```
var c = 'a'; // holds the name of the wanted content, but can also be 'b' or 'c'

$('someSelector').html(eval(c)) // this will just use the content of var c defined above
```

Just use eval to get the variable data.

I just did

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of the other answers work great, such as window["whatever"] = "x"; but I will still put my own answer here, just in case it helps.

My method is to use Object.assign:

```js
let dict = {};
dict["test" + "x"] = "hello";
Object.assign(window, dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

a little improvement over bungdito's answer, use the dynamic variable dynamically

```
var pageNumber = 1;
eval("var text" + pageNumber + "=123456;");
eval(`alert(text${pageNumber})`);
```

note: usage of `eval` is strongly discourgae