# JavaScript Dynamic Variable Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, dynamic-variables

Ok so I want to create variables as a user clicks threw the code every click adds a new variable. I am currently using jquery and javascript I can't do it server side this must be done in the browser.

```
newCount = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML;
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        //set count fast enumeration
        newCount++;
        var hello + newCount = '<p>Hello World</p>';
    });
```

so I want the variables to be hello1, hello2, hello3, hello4, etc.

Comment: Don't use "dynamic variable names". Use the appropriate Map (plain Object) or Sequence (Array).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can only do that with bracket notation, which means you have to attach the variables to something.
The global scope would be window, so that would be `window['hello' + newCount]`, but polluting the global namespace with a bunch of random properties doesn't sound like a good idea, so using an object seems better

```
var vars = {};
var newCount = parseInt($('#hello').html(), 10);

$('.hello').click(function(){
    newCount++;
    vars['hello' + newCount] = '<p>Hello World</p>';
}); 

alert( vars['hello1'] );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zp43W/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `window`

```
var window['hello' + newCount ] = '<p>Hello World</p>';
```

likewise..

```
newCount = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML;
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        //set count fast enumeration
        newCount++;
        var window['hello' + newCount ] = '<p>Hello World</p>';
        alert(window['hello' + newCount ]);
    });
```

Comment: why -1 to my answer? this also will wrk.. its not wrong

Comment: It is wrong. When you get a downvote, maybe you should take the time to test your code.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (as i know) there are 2 ways by which you can create dynamic variables:

```
eval Function
window object
eval:

var pageNumber = 1;
eval("var text" + pageNumber + "=123;");
alert(text1);
window object:

var pageNumber = 1;
window["text" + pageNumber] = 123;
alert(window["text" + pageNumber]);
```

for more inforamtion
[How do i declare and use dynamic variables in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944749/how-do-i-declare-and-use-dynamic-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a simple array to store the variables. Then the object with index n would be variable n etc..

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way

```
var types = {};

for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
types["ashish"+i] = 'The value of dynamic variable, val';
}
```

console.log(types);

you can test it on

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfrJy/89/#&togetherjs=j8OuxM2MQe)

Comment: great stuff, thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

```
var newCount = 0;
$('#btn').click(function(){

    newCount++;
    $('#hello').html('hello' + newCount);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLGLR/)