# Jquery how to assign the name of variable (dynamically)

Tags: jquery

To assign a value to a variable is very simple just do it this way

```
var foo = "bar";
```

But to assign a name to the variable (dynamically) as you have to do?

```
var variableName = "newName";
var variableName = "bar";    // in this case assign new value of variableName
```

Do I have to do it this way?

```
var foo + "_" + variableName = "foo"  // foo_newName = "bar"
```

Comment: i don think this is possible in javascript...you are trying to create variable name dynamically ...how is that possible it not about javascript it not possible in c# also as per my knowldege

Comment: Why do you need this functionality?

Comment: You can only have dynamic properties of objects (including the global object, `window`, if you like), but not local variables.

Comment: variables are nothing but identifiers and they store some value, and any mathematical operation you intend are going to be performed on the values. I can't think what exactly you are trying to solve? creating dynamic variables and accessing them conditionally is native to any programming language including gw-basic : )

Comment: it is possible only if your variables are global or under some scope.

Comment: Why can't you use Arrays for you functionality...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727711/javascript-dynamic-variable-names

Comment: [Look this answer please : Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make dynamic variable using this way

`window['varname'] = "test";`

`alert(varname);`

Comment: Thanks is what I was looking for

Comment: No problem, Please accept the answer if it worked to you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by using eval(), but there are some Reservations about using that method:

```
eval("foo_" + i + "='bar'")
```

Comment: What reservations would those be?

Comment: Hii
This function is used in different languages but Using it (specifically) with javascript on client side (browser) is not that bad.
Here is a link about eval function:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil#

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, you can not create variables like this, however, you can use `object` and set its property.

```
var foo = "bar";
var variableName = "newName";

window[foo + "_" + variableName]  = "foo" ;
console.log(bar_newName);
```

or

```
var foo = "bar";
var variableName = "newName";

var obj = {};

obj[foo + "_" + variableName]  = "foo" ;
console.log(obj["bar_newName"]);
```