# Dynamically calling JSON data using jQuery & HTML5 data-*

Tags: jquery, json, html

I'm working with ExpressionEngine and have converted my channel entries into JSON, that works nicely.

What I am trying to do is populate a Sweet Alert 2 overlay with information from specific JSON objects using an ID stored in a `data-*` attribute.

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
var director_45 = {
  "title": "Andy H",
  "entry_id": 45,
}
```

And if I do a simple jQuery alert like this, it returns my name:

```
alert(director_45.title)
```

However, if I do something like this in jQuery:

```
$('.trigger-director').on('click', function() {
  var director_id = $(this).data('director');
  var director = 'director_' + director_id;
  alert(director.title);
});
```

With this HTML to fire it:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
  <div class="director-box">
    <img src="/images/made/images/uploads/images/Andy_400_300_c1.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="400" height="300" alt="" />
    <h3>Andy H</h3>
    <p>Director</p>
    <a class="trigger-director" data-director="45">Find out more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The alert upon clicking the 'Find out more' link only shows "Undefined".

I've created a jsFiddle link here too - https://jsfiddle.net/zu103vxc/

Any idea what it is that I'm doing wrong and/or missing?

Comment: `var director = window[ 'director_' + director_id];` global variables are properties of the window object and you can access them using array notation

Comment: director is not an object, director is a string 'director_45', ohh @JuanMendes, that one will come handy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Dynamic Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727711/javascript-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: @JuanMendes Interestingly the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: @andy do some closer debugging, if there's a global variable named `director_45`, it will work

Comment: But if the JSON is defined above the jQuery on click, is that not a global variable?

Comment: Type `window.director_45` in the console, that will tell you if it's a global

Comment: Undefined, I'm unsure on how to make it global or how to make this code work as suggested. I tried everything on that other link and no luck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval()

```
var director_45 = {
  "title": "Andy H",
  "entry_id": 45,
}

alert(director_45.title)

$('.trigger-director').on('click', function() {
  var director_id = $(this).data('director');
  var director = 'director_' + director_id;
  alert(eval(director).title);
});
```

or global variables

```
var director_45 = {
  "title": "Andy H",
  "entry_id": 45,
}
window.director_45 = director_45;
alert(director_45.title)

$('.trigger-director').on('click', function() {
  var director_id = $(this).data('director');
  var director = 'director_' + director_id;
  alert(window[director].title);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, decided to go along the global var route. Saved me a massive headache :)