# create variable name from checkbox data

Tags: jquery

```
<input class='setupcheck' type='checkbox' data-x='xpslider'>
<input class='setupcheck' type='checkbox' data-x='xp323'>
<input class='setupcheck' type='checkbox' data-x='xp525'>
```

I need for each checkbox to create a variable named as its `data('x')` and give it a value `1` if it is checked, else - value `0`;

Something like this:

```
$('.setupcheck').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        variable named $(this).data('x') = 1;
    }
    else{
        variable named $(this).data('x') = 0;
    }
}
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727711/javascript-dynamic-variable-names).

Comment: `variable named $(this).data('x') = 1; `???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them global variables then use:

```
var storeObj = window;

$('.setupcheck').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        storeObj[$(this).data('x')] = 1;
    }
    else{
        storeObj[$(this).data('x')] = 0;
    }
});
```

Now check `console.log(xpslider);`

Or if you want to store them in separate then:

```
var storeObj = {};
```

and use as `console.log(storeObj.xpslider);`