# jQuery create variable reference inside .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a couple of applications which use jquery 3.2.1 and DataTables 1.10.15.

In the first application - which all works fine - I made a reference to *a single* DataTable as follows:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({ ... });
```

If I need to reference that DataTable it's easy because I can do this:

```
var row = myTable.row(tr);
```

In the second application there are *multiple* DataTables on one page. The way in which these were created is using `$.each()` in jquery:

```
$.each($('table'), function () {
    var dt_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#' + dt_id).DataTable({ ... });
});
```

This targets each `<table>` which is present in the HTML present on page load. It creates a variable called `dt_id` which has the value of the ID of the `<table>`. It then initialises the DataTable on it.

So if, for example, I have 3 tables:

```
<table id="tableA"> ... </table>
<table id="tableB"> ... </table>
<table id="tableC"> ... </table>
```

I end up with 3 DataTables being initialised on ID's `#tableA`, `#tableB` and `#tableC`.

The problem I'm having is that outside the `$.each()` I want to be able to refer to a specific DataTable when the user clicks on a particular row inside it. So if for example the user clicks a `<tr>` inside `#tableB` I need a variable which refers to that table.

I don't know the best way of creating these in my code? I've read [JavaScript Dynamic Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727711/javascript-dynamic-variable-names) and one option would be to dynamically create a variable name, e.g.

```
$.each($('table'), function () {
    var dt_id = $(this).attr('id');

    var dynamicVar = $('#' + dt_id).DataTable({ ... });
});
```

But how do I create that `dynamicVar` at this point?

Another option I thought of would be to read the ID of the table that the user has clicked (e.g. If the user clicks a `<tr>` then find the ID of the parent `<table>`, e.g. `#tableB`). Not sure if that's viable and even if it is, how do you access `.DataTable(...)` from that?

Comment: You can get a reference to the Datatable after initialisation from the jQuery object: `var dtA = $('#tableA').DataTable(); var dtB = $('#tableB').DataTable();`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok, so is the best way then to try and identify the ID (`#tableA`) based on the `<tr>` the user has clicked and then use the snippet you provided?

Comment: Yes, if you have a reference to a clicked `tr`, then you can do `$(this).closest('table').DataTable()`, where `this` is the `tr` itself

Comment: Here's the docs regarding accessing the DT from a jQuery object: https://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API

Comment: There's no need to select an element by ID when you already have the element itself. Just use `$(this)` instead of `$('#' + dt_id)`

Comment: Couldn`t you create an object where you store the data tables by using the ID as its key.  For example var myDictionnary = {}; Then in the $.each function myDictionnary[dt_id] = $('#' + dt_id).DataTable({ ... });  One more thing can you replace $('#' + dt_id) by $(this).  If so you could get rid on the line var dt_id = $(this).attr('id');