# Dynamic variable name array with an id by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've to do a variable array with variable name based on ID set by PHP echo.

```
    <script>
  var dat<?php echo $id; ?>;
  dat<?php echo $id; ?> = ["ecc..","ecc.."];
  </script>

jQuery("#name").html(dat[0]+id); // doesn't work
```

id is already set by a function, the question is: can i write the VAR correctly including also the PHP ID? Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Java programming? I don't see any Java in the code above.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: yes javascript!

Comment: OK, I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i declare and use dynamic variables in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944749/how-do-i-declare-and-use-dynamic-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script>
var dat<?php echo $id; ?>;
dat<?php echo $id; ?> = ["ecc..","ecc.."];

console.log(dat<?php echo $id; ?>[1]);
jQuery("#name").html(dat<?php echo $id; ?>[0]);
</script>
```

The reason it wasnt working is because `dat` is `dat#` where `#` is an id.

You must access an array element on `dat#`, not `dat[pos]#`.

Comment: $id variable is in a foreach and i can't write it also in the function...

Comment: Solved, close thread, thx :)